# Deleting specific files in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-io

So I've created a small administration panel with `php` that will upload files into a directory that will be shown on the main page.
Now the thing is, how do I delete a file?
I've already seen that people are using `Ajax` and `jQuery` to do this but I don't understand how to do this with a button.

This is my function that generates the image and the delete button, but when someone click on the button it should delete the associated image, I don't get it how to pass the image path or something :

```
$dirname = "img_show/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($images as $image) {
     echo '<img src="'.$image.'" width="25%" /><br/>';
     echo '<form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Effacer" />
            </form>';
 }
```

Comment: @TristanVerneesch are you asking how to delete a image which is uploaded by a administrator?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do. The admin has a list of all uploaded images and should be able to delete a specific one.

Comment: Easy. Please do update your question with a snap of the database table. So that I can provide you a clean code.also please do accept the edit if its match to your question

Comment: with current code does your images get display ?

Comment: There is no database, everything is running without a database. The image just needs to appear with no extra information. Is there a way to do it without a database? The files are stored in the same directory as the admin page anyways.

Comment: Yes they do display

Comment: You don't need Ajax for this but it might make sense. It could make for a nicer UI, but that's a decision you need to make about how you want your site to work. First decide how you want to do it, then research how to do it.

Comment: if there is no DB how does administrator upload images. Does administrator uploads images to server by manually. Is this is a working site?

Comment: Well can't I just select a file and delete it, I find it pretty useless to create a database for that. I just don't see how I can run `unlink($myFile)` and replace the variable with the file that's above the button

Comment: It just uploads a file to the server and put it into a directory

Comment: @Nipun a database is not needed for uploading files. Nor is it necessarily required for working out which user is admin or not (if that's what you're trying to ask)

Comment: "I just don't see how I can run unlink($myFile) and replace the variable with the file that's above the button" ...if you put the same variable into a hidden field in your form then it will be sent to the server as a $_POST variable when you submit the form

Comment: @ADyson usually what I do is when uploading i set the url into db table and then fetch it in front-end. That's why I asked something like that. However I know images can be uploaded with out a db. But when we go for deletion how could we delete it without a db. If you could provide some links where we can learn this, it will be a great help. Thanks

Comment: @Nipun what OP is doing here is simply passing the filename as the item to delete. You don't need to read some other tutorial to realise that. Since all the images are in the same folder, then by implication all the file names must be unique, so it can work. I'm not saying it's the best way, or even a good way at all, but it's possible. OP should probably add measures to ensure that other files (e.g. PHP files, or files in other folders) cannot be deleted by a malicious request...at the moment there are security issues with this code but on a basic level it can do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to delete files that are retrieved from the "img_show" directory and not storing it in the database.

The easiest way to delete the selected file is to update your code with the following,

```
// Delete an image if the delete button was clicked
if(isset($_POST['delete']) && $_POST['delete'] == 'Effacer') {
    unlink($_POST['file']);
}


// Print the available list of images in the directory
$dirname = "img_show/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" width="25%" /><br/>';
    echo '<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="'. $image .'" />
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Effacer" />
    </form>';
}
```